# Woocommerce custom taxonomy order

Tags: categories, customization, taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic, order

I have a custom order of my taxonomies in Woocommerce/Taxonomy Order.

When I display them, they get printed in alphabetical order.

How can I prevent this behavior and print them in the order I selected?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using any plugin or you did it manually using coding ?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using the [get_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) function to generate a list of the items in a custom taxonomy. I'm sure there are other good ways of doing this, but there are plenty of parameters here you can try out to get the order you need.

```
    $terms = get_terms( 'custom_taxonomy_here', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0' );
        if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            echo '<li>' . $term->name . '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
```

In the example above, `orderby` orders the terms by their count (but there are other arguments for a different order) and `hide_empty` to display terms whether or not they are associated with a post.